# How do I inherit constructors in Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

How can the following code be improved? I'm not keen on the casts in Subclass or the duplication between object Superclass and object Subclass

```
class Superclass {
  val bitSet = BitSet.empty  
  def += (bitSet:BitSet) = { this.bitSet | bitSet ; this }
  def += (ints:Array[Int]) = { ints.foreach { bitSet += _ } ; this }
  override def toString = bitSet.toString
}

object Superclass {
  def apply(bitSet:BitSet) = new Superclass += bitSet
  def apply(ints:Array[Int]) = new Superclass += ints
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
  override def += (bitSet:BitSet) = (super.+= (bitSet)).asInstanceOf[Subclass]
  override def += (ints:Array[Int]) = (super.+= (ints)).asInstanceOf[Subclass]
}

object Subclass {
  def apply(bitSet:BitSet) = new Subclass += bitSet
  def apply(ints:Array[Int]) =  new Subclass += ints
}

object SubclassTest extends App {
  println(Subclass(Array(1,2,3)))
}
```

Comment: Why not change superclass to trait?

Comment: In singleton implementation of super class there is a signs of conversion so I would say you should use implicits somewhere

Comment: You are trying to mix FP and imperative style. Normally for mutable objects I wouldn't return `this` and `+=` would work as implemented in `Superclass`. Chaining mutable objects could be misleading.

Comment: Also, you can avoid cast with `{ super.+= (bitSet); this }`

Comment: @VictorMoroz += returns collection in scala libs, so just adhering to convention by returning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding cast, you can make your `Superclass` methods return the parent class' type:

```
  def += (bitSet: BitSet): this.type = { this.bitSet | bitSet; this }
```

Now, you don't need to override them:

```
  class Subclass extends Superclass
  val subclass: Subclass = new Subclass += BitSet.empty
```

The returned value of `+=` is of type `Subclass`.

It may be worth mentioning though, that your `+=` method doen't do anything: `BitSet.|` does not modify the bitset, it just returns a copy, which you then promptly discard.
The other one does work, but keeping mutable state around is generally frowned upon, unless you have a really, really good reason for it (which you most probably do not).

As for the duplication in `apply`, there isn't very much you can do about it generically. In this particular case, I would recommend to just get rid of it entirely, and make the bitSet a constructor parameter:

```
  class Superclass(val bitSet: BitSet = BitSet.empty) { 
   ...
  }
  class Subclass(bitSet: BitSet = BitSet.empty) 
    extends Superclass(bitSet)
```

Now, instead of `apply`, you can just do

```
  new Subclass(bitSet)
  new Superclass(bitSet)
```

or
      new Subclass() += ints
      new Subperclass() += ints

Comment: Love this.type. I meant { this.bitSet |= bitSet; this }. In the real thing of which this is a great simplification the constructor is quite expensive. I use += and -= to avoid lots of instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

For factoring out the duplicate parts of the companion objects you might be able to use a variation on the template pattern. (together with using `this.type` where possible)

```
trait Factory[T <: Superclass] {
  protected def create: T
  def apply(bitSet:BitSet): T = create += bitSet
  def apply(ints:Array[Int]): T = create += ints
}

object Superclass extends Factory[Superclass] {
  protected def create = new Superclass
}

object Subclass extends Factory[Subclass] {
  protected def create = new Subclass
}
```